# ESLint working but don't know what are all rules it is checking

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

I have installed the **ESLint extension ( by Drik Breaumer)** in vs code. Its running and also showing errors

But what are the rules its checking I don't have any **.eslintric** files in my repository?

In the package.json file, I have this configuration

```
"eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    }
```

how do I add more rules for this ESLinter or disable the rules ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Create React App. You can extend or replace the default config by following the directions on the Create React App documentation.

[Create React App - Extending or replacing the default ESLint config](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#extending-or-replacing-the-default-eslint-config)